# Official Ubuntu 18.04 image for AWS

Tags: server, amazon-ec2

I was waiting for release of Ubuntu 18.04 to upgrade my old server and want to create a fresh EC2 instance from Ubuntu 18.04. It's not available yet in "Quick Start" (official AMI) page.

But I noticed ami-331d3bd8 from [this page](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) is available on EC2 Community AMI page.

I want to ask if AWS official Ubuntu image is same as provided by Ubuntu or they create a new official image themselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research earlier and also reached AWS support for comments.

And the short answer is: **Yes** they are official images

AWS official images for Ubuntu as same as those provided by the Canonical organisation. Only thing AWS does is, mark them as official in "Getting Started" page.

Important thing to note is that they are not currently available under Free tier unless specified under the image in future.

To find Official Canonical Ubuntu 18.04 image for AWS, visit https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ and filter for the particular image, in the particular region. And then use that AMI id to search in AWS console.

Comment: Are you sure it is not available under Free Tier?

Comment: @Suncatcher You can check the AWS portal (maybe it's now). They always add a note to images with free tier eligibiliy. It was not at the time of writing this answer.

Comment: @VarunAgw, did you need to make some sort of subscription procedure in order to use that AMI? I have read some reviews from Canonical products in the AWS Marketplace that say that you should subscribe.

Comment: @Claudix AWS marketplace is a different thing. These are community Ami

Comment: @VarunAgw Thanks. I have accessed to the resource you linked and, after setting some filters, I get multiple images even with the same release date. For example, images "ami-d2414e38", "ami-39c28c41" and "ami-daf040a7" have all the same values in all columns but the "Zone" column. Are they actually the same but just hosted in servers of different zones?

Comment: @Claudix Yes! They are only available in a particular zone. You cannot access image from a different zone

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ask if AWS official Ubuntu image is same as provided by Ubuntu or they create a new official image themselves?

No, they are not the same. AWS create their own AMI for officially supported free tier eligible Ubuntu distribution that you see on "Quick Start" page.